# Selecting multiple items from listbox to add to 2D array and pass to another page UWP C#

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp

I am trying to select multiple (2) items from a listbox and add these values to a 2D array, this array gets passed to the next page to output order info from a menu. When I go to the second page the array is passed but only displays the first selected item from the listbox on the first page? Is it because I am not loading the array correctly in my code?

First page code:

```
        class order
{
  public string[,] orderItems = new string[3,3];

}
public sealed partial class foodMenu : Page
{

    int x = 0;
    order newOrder = new order();
    public foodMenu()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void ReturnHomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }

    private void breakfastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        menuList.Items.Clear();
        menuList.Items.Add("Eggs");
        menuList.Items.Add("Bacon");
        menuList.Items.Add("Cereal");
        menuList.Items.Add("Orange Juice");
        menuList.Items.Add("Coffee");


    }
    private void lunchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        menuList.Items.Clear();
        menuList.Items.Add("Ham Sandwich");
        menuList.Items.Add("Turkey Sandwich");
        menuList.Items.Add("Salad");
        menuList.Items.Add("Soup");
        menuList.Items.Add("Soda");
        menuList.Items.Add("Juice");

    }
    private void dinnerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        menuList.Items.Clear();
        menuList.Items.Add("Pasta");
        menuList.Items.Add("Lobster");
        menuList.Items.Add("Ham");
        menuList.Items.Add("Pot Roast");
        menuList.Items.Add("Wine");
        menuList.Items.Add("Juice");
    }
    private void addOrderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         newOrder.orderItems[x,x] = Convert.ToString(menuList.SelectedItem);
        x++;

    }
    private void orderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(orderConfirmation), newOrder);
    }


}
```

}

Second page code:

```
        public sealed partial class orderConfirmation : Page
{
    public orderConfirmation()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        order orderOutputInfo = (order)e.Parameter;
        string[,] orderItems = new string[3, 3];

            orderItems[0,0] = orderOutputInfo.orderItems[0,0];
            orderOutput.Items.Add(orderItems[0,0]);
            orderItems[1, 1] = orderOutputInfo.orderItems[1, 1];
            orderOutput.Items.Add(orderItems[1, 1]);
            orderItems[2, 2] = orderOutputInfo.orderItems[2, 2];
            orderOutput.Items.Add(orderItems[2, 2]);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "menuList" is the ListBox.

```
menuList.SelectedItem
```

Return is singular.

```
menuList.SelectedItems
```

Return is multiple which I think might be what you're looking for.